# Identity Column values jumps to 1000 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Identity value jumps to 1000 on my client's computer.

I have searched a lot. I  know that I have to use trace flag `-T272` but client's computer doesn't have **SQL Server Configuration Manager**. How to set trace flag on `.MDF` files?

Comment: What you mean by "jumps"?

Comment: when i insert Data identity column value jumps from 3 to 1004, Means jump of 1000 indexes. @Fabio

Comment: There is plenty of information on identity columns, they all come with a warning that there is _no guarantee at all_ that the identity values generated will be consecutive. Identity columns are not for generating consecutive values, and you should not use them for that. An identity column that is also a primary key is used for generating unique identifiers that uniquely identify a row, that is all.

Comment: but now i have used them, So please tell me how to set trace flag on .mdf files? @TT.

Comment: You can't do this on an .MDF, but on a SQL Server instance. Read thos on [DBCC TRACEON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-traceon-transact-sql).

Comment: how to use DBCC TRACEON ? client dont have SQL server installed? i supplied him .mdf files with my application.

Comment: @JamshaidTariq, SQL Server must be installed to read mdf files. If you don't see the SQL Server Configuration Manager shortcut, the file name will be similar to `SQLServerManager*.msc` in the `C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64` folder. The name (and perhaps location) may vary depending on SQL Server version and OS.